# Circuit Breaker is not showing in component section in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, circuit-breaker

I configured **actuator** and **reselience4j** in **application.yml** file

Here is my **application.yml** file

```
management:
  endpoint:
    health:
      show-details: always
    circuitbreakers:
      enabled: true
    web:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: health

resilience4j:
  circuitbreaker:
    instances:
      ratingHotelBreaker:
        register-health-indicator: true
        event-consumer-buffer-size: 10
        failure-rate-threshold: 50
        minimum-number-of-calls: 5
        automatic-transition-from-open-to-half-open-enabled: true
        wait-duration-in-open-state: 6s
        permitted-number-of-calls-in-half-open-state: 3
        sliding-window-size: 10
        sliding-window-type: count_based
```

This is my pom.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.user.service</groupId>
    <artifactId>UserService</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>UserService</name>
    <description>This is User Service</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.0</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.resilience4j/resilience4j-spring-boot -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>resilience4j-spring-boot2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Still I am not getting circuit breaker configuration after hitting **actuator/health** URL.

**Here is Image what I am getting**

[In this image circuit breaker section is not there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cu7Aa.png)

What is missing in configuration ?

Comment: Can you add your pom.xml to the question. I suspect a "starter" is missing

Comment: Yes I added pom.xml file. Please suggest

Answer (score 3):

The application.yml `management` & `resilience4j` hierarchies are wrong. The following works:

```
management:
  health:
    circuitbreakers:
      enabled: true
  endpoint:
    health:
      show-details: always
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: health

resilience4j:
  circuitbreaker:
    configs:
      default:
        registerHealthIndicator: true
    instances:
      ratingHotelBreaker:
        register-health-indicator: true
        event-consumer-buffer-size: 10
        failure-rate-threshold: 50
        minimum-number-of-calls: 5
        automatic-transition-from-open-to-half-open-enabled: true
        wait-duration-in-open-state: 6s
        permitted-number-of-calls-in-half-open-state: 3
        sliding-window-size: 10
        sliding-window-type: COUNT_BASED
```

`/actuator/health` returns as follows for your pom file:

```
{
   "status":"UP",
   "components":{
      "circuitBreakers":{
         "status":"UP",
         "details":{
            "ratingHotelBreaker":{
               "status":"UP",
               "details":{
                  "failureRate":"-1.0%",
                  "failureRateThreshold":"50.0%",
                  "slowCallRate":"-1.0%",
                  "slowCallRateThreshold":"100.0%",
                  "bufferedCalls":0,
                  "slowCalls":0,
                  "slowFailedCalls":0,
                  "failedCalls":0,
                  "notPermittedCalls":0,
                  "state":"CLOSED"
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "clientConfigServer":{
         "status":"UNKNOWN",
         "details":{
            "error":"no property sources located"
         }
      },
      "discoveryComposite":{
         "status":"UP",
         "components":{
            "discoveryClient":{
               "status":"UP",
               "details":{
                  "services":[
                     
                  ]
               }
            },
            "eureka":{
               "description":"Eureka discovery client has not yet successfully connected to a Eureka server",
               "status":"UP",
               "details":{
                  "applications":{
                     
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "diskSpace":{
         "status":"UP",
         "details":{
            "total":252011958272,
            "free":75452362752,
            "threshold":10485760,
            "path":"C:\\workspaces\\stackoverflow_workspace\\spring6\\.",
            "exists":true
         }
      },
      "ping":{
         "status":"UP"
      },
      "refreshScope":{
         "status":"UP"
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the ideal configuration to enable health metric endpoint for the circuit breaker. Refere here for more at [Health endpoint seciton.](https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/getting-started-3)

**application.yml**

```
management.health.circuitbreakers.enabled: true
management.health.ratelimiters.enabled: true

resilience4j.circuitbreaker:
  configs:
    default:
      registerHealthIndicator: true
```

Answer (score 0):

just change
circuitbreaker to circuitbreaker**s**

management.health.circuitbreaker**s**.enabled=true

it helped me